# Can an occupation be used as a pronoun?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I was wondering if an occupation can be used as a pronoun? Let me explain. If I were to say:

> The mayor is coming to town.

I believe that's a pronoun. (Correct me if I'm wrong.) But what about something like this:

> The mayor, John Appleseed, is coming to town.

Would 'the mayor' be considered a pronoun for the future?

Comment: It's not a pronoun, it's a noun.

Comment: Why isn't it standing in place of a specific noun?

Comment: Because it *is* a specific noun, it refers to a specific person, the mayor of the city. It's no different from "The *dog* is on the bed" or "The *book* is in the library"

Comment: http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/pronouns-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [The Oxford Dictionaries site](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mayor), "mayor" is a noun signifying, "the elected head of a city, town, or other municipality". Although, in a specific context, the phrase, "the mayor" may designate a unique individual, it remains a common noun phrase. The only [pronouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun) that can be used as the subject of an English declarative sentence are the 7 nominative case personal pronouns (I, we, you, he, she, it, they) and the 6 demonstrative pronouns (this, that, these, those, none, neither). In the example sentence, a [proper noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun) (John Appleseed) is replaced with a substitute common noun (the mayor), but that does not make the substituted word a pronoun.